# adding bottom border on navigation hover without changing position on everything below

Tags: html, css, navigation, hover

I want to make my navigation have bottom border while in hover, but then it moves all my content 3px down. How do I make it work without moving all content down.

CSS of navigation :

```
nav {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;

}
nav ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
nav ul li {
    float: left;
    width: 19.7%;
    background-color: #e88610;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 3px solid gray;
    border-top: 1px solid gray;
}
nav ul li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
}
nav ul li:first-child {
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
}
nav ul li a {
    text-decoration:none;
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0px;
    color: white;
}
nav ul li a:visited {
    color: white;
}
nav ul li a:hover{
    background-color: orange;
    border-bottom: 3px solid gray;
}
```

CSS of content below :

```
#novi_clanak {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.65);
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 40px;
    margin-top:35px;
}
```

Comment: where is your HTML for `nav` ?

Comment: It's like every list, i don't think it's necessary to post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially by adding a border, you're extending the nav by 3px. Have a look at the `box-sizing` property of CSS at http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_box-sizing.asp. You want your `nav ul li a:hover` to have `box-sizing: border-box;`. That will take the bottom border's 3px into account for the element height.

Alternatively, shorten the `nav ul li a:hover` height by 3px (set it to 39px).

Comment: box-sizing didn't do anything, content is still moving

Comment: How about setting the `nav ul li a:hover { height: 39px; }`?

Comment: I put it to 38px and works like charm now, thanks :)

Comment: Drago mi je da mogu pomoći :)

Answer (score 1):

add to nav css

```
position: fixed;
```

Comment: it works on full screen but when I resize it for responibilite check, it's broken

Comment: Try adding some media queries in your css  file and then add position: fixed;